# Suggestion on File I/O opertion with 1024 bytes chunks

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hi I am a ruby on rails developer can any body help me in doing File I/O operation with 1024 bytes chunk at a time.

Comment: The question is very vague - what is the goal you're trying to reach with the File I/O? What have you tried? How did it differ from the results you were expecting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/IO.html#M002270 :

```
f = File.new("testfile")
f.read(1024)
```